# Speeding up rotation matrix calculation with numba

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, numba

I'm trying to speed up a set of rotation matrix calculations that result in a 3D matrix (dimensions = 3x3xnumv, where numv is the number of vertices). So far my jit function results in a significantly slower calculation.

```
from numpy import sin, cos, ones, sqrt, array, float64, zeros, isnan, shape
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numba import jit
from numba import float64 as _float64

def calculate_rot_matrix(rot_edges, kb, k):
'''
Calculates rotation matrices for set of input 2 edges
Returns rot matrix with shape (3, 3, max_edges)
edges are different for vertices vs. edges (but only vertices are kept)
'''
    b           = kb / k  # global kb
    b[isnan(b)] = 0.0
    sin_theta   = norm(rot_edges, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1) * k / 2.0
    cos_theta   = sqrt(ones(shape(sin_theta)) - sin_theta ** 2.0)
    n1, n2, n3  = b[:, 0], b[:, 1], b[:, 2]
    s, c        = sin_theta.reshape(-1), cos_theta.reshape(-1)
    # get rotation matrices
    R = array([[c + n1**(2.0) * (1.0 - c), n1*n2*(1.0 - c) - s*n3, n3*n1 * (1.0 - c) + s*n2],
           [n1*n2*(1.0 - c) + s*n3, c + n2**(2.0) * (1.0 - c), n3*n2 * (1.0 - c) - s*n1],
           [n1*n3*(1.0 - c) - s*n2, n2*n3*(1.0 - c) + s*n1, c + n3**(2.0) * (1.0 - c)]])
    # fix empty rotations
    R[isnan(R)] = 0.0
    return R

@jit((_float64[:,:], _float64[:,:], _float64[:]))
def jit_calculate_rot_matrix(rot_edges, kb, k):
'''
Calculates rotation matrices for set of input 2 edges
Returns rot matrix with shape (3, 3, max_edges)
edges are different for vertices vs. edges (but only vertices are kept)
'''
    b           = kb / k  # global kb
    b[isnan(b)] = 0.0
    sin_theta   = norm(rot_edges, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1) * k / 2.0
    cos_theta   = sqrt(ones(shape(sin_theta)) - sin_theta ** 2.0)
    n1, n2, n3  = b[:, 0], b[:, 1], b[:, 2]
    s, c        = sin_theta.reshape(-1), cos_theta.reshape(-1)
    # get rotation matrices
    R = array([[c + n1**(2.0) * (1.0 - c), n1*n2*(1.0 - c) - s*n3, n3*n1 * (1.0 - c) + s*n2],
           [n1*n2*(1.0 - c) + s*n3, c + n2**(2.0) * (1.0 - c), n3*n2 * (1.0 - c) - s*n1],
           [n1*n3*(1.0 - c) - s*n2, n2*n3*(1.0 - c) + s*n1, c + n3**(2.0) * (1.0 - c)]])
    # fix empty rotations
    R[isnan(R)] = 0.0
    return R

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cProfile
    import pstats
    import cStringIO
    import traceback

    numv = 100
    rot_edges = zeros((numv, 3), dtype=float64)
    rot_edges[:, 1] = 1.0
    kb = zeros((numv, 3), dtype=float64)
    # k  = norm(kb, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
    k  = ones((numv, 1), dtype=float64)

    profile = cProfile.Profile()
    profile.enable()
    # =======================================================================
    # profile enabled
    # =======================================================================
    for i in range(10000):
        R = calculate_rot_matrix(rot_edges, kb, k)
    for i in range(10000):
        R_jit = jit_calculate_rot_matrix(rot_edges, kb, k)
    # =======================================================================
    # profile disabled
    # =======================================================================
    profile.disable()
    stream = cStringIO.StringIO()
    sortby = 'cumulative'
    ps = pstats.Stats(profile, stream=stream).sort_stats(sortby)
    ps.strip_dirs()
    ps.sort_stats(1)
    ps.print_stats(20)
    print stream.getvalue()
```

Based on the documentation, I think the speed gains I can get would be from running the jitted function with nopython=True as a parameter. However, while some operations will work on arrays (sin, cos), I want to know if there's any "norm" type function (operating on a numv x 3 matrix of vectors, producing a numv x 1 vector). I also am calling reshape a number of times to be able to broadcast to the correct shape, and I think that since this is a "python" feature, it can't be translated to jit nopython.

Comment: If you can't run it in nopython mode then it's unlikely you'll get any reasonable speedups with numba. Try to do the operations "per hand" without using the vectorized functions and boolean masking then you might be able to compile it with nopython. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Reshaping is not an expensive operation since usually only strides are manipulated;
2. *"I want to know if there's any "norm" type function (operating on a numv x 3 matrix of vectors, producing a numv x 1 vector)"* I think `numpy.linalg.norm()` already does what you want - just use its `axis` parameter:

   ```
   np.linalg.norm(some_array, axis=0)
   ```
3. Most of your operations are already vectorized and probably internally (to `numpy`) written in C and I do not see how much you would gain from having this code accelerated with `numba`.

Comment: I'm using np.linalg.norm already, but I don't think that will transfer to nopython mode (not in the supported functions list). Thanks for the other tips though!

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear (to me) what you really wanted in a norm() function. If `norm()` is the only thing that prevents you from "translating to jit nonpython", then I would suggest that you express norm() through supported functions such as np.sqrt(np.sum(some_array**2, axis=0)) (adjust axis according to the shape of your array).